# Redirect to the correct application given a subdomain

Tags: php, apache, redirect, yii

Environment:

- Apache 2.4
- PHP 7
- Yii 2.0.9

I want to redirect a client by checking his subdomain.
There are two issues regarding the redirection: a) from his URL, I need to select a
specific application version and b) the client can not be sent to a different URL.

Scenario:

1. Access the subdomain.example.com (URL)
2. index.php triggers a query to the database and find out which version of the application should be redirected
3. The client is redirected to the correct application (v1, v2, ..., vN) in the same HOST
4. The URL must remain the same
5. Each version of the application has its own index

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want that `http://asia1.example.com/orders/view` to run `/var/www/example/v1/index.php` and `http://asia2.example.com/orders/view` to run `/var/www/example/v2/index.php`, is that so ? If true, than you can simply map the subdomains at different virtual hosts with different paths at the local filesystem of the server. If you do not want to have separate copies of the code for each subdomain - you may point the WHOLE domain (ignoring subdomains in Apache) to `/var/www/app` and then in each PHP file check `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` and decide which code to execute

Comment: Yes [@IVO GELOV](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5962802/ivo-gelov), I would like to map the subdomains with different virtual hosts, but I would like to leave the mapping dynamic. 

For example, for each subdomain, I have to query the database to determine which application to use (v1, v2, ...), because there is a dependency with another system. 

So, I would like to find a way to avoid manually configuring each vhost, or try to abstract the choice of an application in the centralized index.php. 

Notice that, the URL must remain the same. Regards! =)

Comment: Okay, then what about using `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` to check the domain, then ask the database to determine the application version, assign the obtained value to a session variable  and then rely on this variable in all the rest PHP scripts ? You may even use the auto-prepend feature of PHP (http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-automatically-append-prepend) - place your checks for application version in the prepended script, so that all of your other scripts transparently receive the already determined application version. Do you understand what I mean ?